# MP4Box is converting H.264 video to AVC -> File won't import into iTunes

Tags: video, mp4, h.264

I use iTunes.  That's not going to change any time soon.  I'm trying to concatenate a 2-disk movie that I've ripped using Handbrake.  Each file was encoded with identical settings:  There is an H.264 video track, 4 different audio tracks, and a chapter track (according to Subler).

When I use MP4Box to concatenate the files using`mp4box -cat file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 new.mp4`
the file seems to be concatenated, but when I open it up in Subler, the video stream has been converted to AVC3, and the video won't import into the iTunes library.  I've saved the file again in Subler, checking the 64-bit offset with no success.  Final movie size is ~7.9GB. (It's nearly 4 hours)

I'm out of ideas here.  I had no problems with the first movie (exact same process, AFAICT), but the next two are giving me fits.  As of this moment I'm trying again with the verbose mode on to see if I can figure anything else out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is a question on how to use a piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h.264 is the same thing as AVC, avc3 is a container level box to record the codec extradata. avc3 was introduced for fragmented mp4 support. iTunes will not support fragmented mp4. The fact that mp4box is generating an avc3 seems to be a bug. https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/13